# Python selenium object repository

Tags: python, python-2.x, selenium

I was trying to create the selenium web element object repository in python. I have come up with three ways to do so. However, I am new to python so I am not sure which one is better than other.

**Note:** I am using Page object pattern for writing my tests, however just for understanding and simplicity I have put all the function in one file (class).

**First: Using Decorator**

```
def FindBy(by, value):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(self):
            return self.driver.find_element(by, value)
        return wrapper
    return decorator


class TestGoogle(object):

    @FindBy(By.NAME, "q")
    def search_input(self): pass

    def test_search(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("https://google.com")
        self.search_input().send_keys("selenium python")
```

**Second & Third: using Lambda and Method**

```
class TestGoogle(object):

    def find_element(self, by, value):
        return self.driver.find_element(by, value)

    def search_input(self): return self.find_element(By.NAME, "q")

    search_input_1 = lambda self: self.find_element(By.NAME, "q")

    def test_search(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("https://google.com")
        self.search_input().send_keys("selenium python")
        self.search_input_1().clear()
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were to use "find by" PageFactory-like notation in Python, I would go with the one proposed [here](https://jeremykao.wordpress.com/2015/06/10/pagefactory-pattern-in-python/) - similar to your versions, but more concise and supports more features:

```
from pageobject_support import callable_find_by as find_by

class GoogleSearchPage(object):
    search_input = find_by(how=By.NAME, using='q')
```

---

Old Answer (in case there is anything useful there)

I would go further and follow the [Page Object pattern](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html), creating abstractions for the pages and elements you are working with, as demonstrated in the [selenium documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html). This way you are isolating your locators from the logic of the test providing an "API" to work with a particular page.

Here is one way to do it - pay attention to how simple and concise the actual test has become:

```
import unittest

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


class MainPageLocators(object):
    """A class for main page locators. All main page locators should come here"""
    SEARCH_INPUT = (By.NAME, 'q')


class BasePage(object):
    """Base class to initialize the base page that will be called from all pages"""

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver


class MainPage(BasePage):
    """Home page action methods come here."""

    def search(self, search_query):
        """Triggers the search"""
        search_input = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.SEARCH_INPUT)
        search_input.send_keys(search_query)
        search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


class TestGoogle(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("https://google.com")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

    def test_search(self):
        main_page = MainPage(self.driver)
        main_page.search("selenium python")
```

Note that you may also want a separate class for an element, but this should be good enough to get you started.

Also note that I'm using a `unittest.TestCase` as a base class for your test which, aside from bringing other benefits, allows to nicely start and close a browser via `setUp` and `tearDown`.

Comment: I am also using the page object patter. however this is just for the `self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.SEARCH_INPUT)` syntax, similar to how we do in **PageFactory** in Java

Comment: @GaurangShah gotcha, updated the answer a bit. Check it out, thanks.